# AWS ec2 + Jenkins controller on docker swarm agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, jenkins-agent

Sorry for confusing you, but I am lost with tones of plugins, info, methods, etc.
I will try explain my workflow and what I am trying to do.

---

I got three ec2 instances( controller, node1, node2 )
-  in controller I got Docker and I did (docker swarm init --advertise-addr )

- install Jenkins on ec2-Master (docker service create --name jenkins-master -p 50000:50000 -p 80:8080 jenkins)
- in the master ec2 create a SSH key (ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “blabla@gmail.com")
- in the ec2 node1 and node2 (echo “ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAA.... blabla@gmail.com”  >> ~/.ssh/authorised_keys

I created new node in Jenkins (config):[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR4Xv.png)

The console output: [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbPzI.png)

Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for ec2-user (credentialId...) is that problem in Docker or?

Do you know any easiest way to create new Jenkins node?

Comment: The ssh-keys are of node and not of the docker container, that is why it is not working. You need to have those generated keys inside the docker container

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, I will try :